# DropDownList getting more than one values in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I am working on a membership app created in MVC3. I have two different kinds of members **Organisation** and **Individual**. After they paying the membership fee, I need to track their payment history. Thus, in the first row (the field after text **Member**),  I need to display the "OrganisationName" of **Organisation** and "MemberForname" of **Individual** in DropDownList. But now I can only display either "OrganisationName" or "MemberForname". I tried a lot, but still can't figure it out by displaying both. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.[The screen shot above only displays "OrganisationName", and the bottom one only displays "MemberForname"].

```
        <td>
            Member
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("member", ((IEnumerable<ProActiveMembership.Areas.Members.Models.Member>)ViewBag.PossibleMembers).Select(option => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Html.DisplayTextFor(_ => option.Forename).ToString(),
                //Text = Html.DisplayTextFor(_ => option.OrganisationName).ToString(),

                Value = option.MemberID.ToString(),
                Selected = (Model != null) && (option.MemberID == Model.MemberID)
            }), "Choose...", new { id = "ddl" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberID)
        </td>
```

[image]

Comment: How about adding a property onto `Member` which would return both `Forename` and `OrganisationName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `Text` property like this: `Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", option.Forename, option.OrganisationName)`

Your code would then look like this:

```
<td>
    Member
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList("member", ((IEnumerable<ProActiveMembership.Areas.Members.Models.Member>)ViewBag.PossibleMembers).Select(option => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", option.Forename, option.OrganisationName),
        Value = option.MemberID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (option.MemberID == Model.MemberID)
    }), "Choose...", new { id = "ddl" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberID)
</td>
```

As andreister suggests you can also add a member to `ProActiveMembership.Areas.Members.Models.Member` that returns the full name. Something like this:

```
public string FullName { get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", Forename, OrganisationName); } }
```

You can then use the new member like this:

```
Text = option.FullName
```

Comment: No problems, glad I could help.

Comment: Mattias, I have a similar problem about dropDownList, I tried it all this morning since I am a fresh man in mvc3, can I send you the code to give me some ideas? thanks